# Property is undefined in for...in loop but I can access it manually

Tags: javascript, object, for-in-loop

I define an object like this:

```
let users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: false
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    age: 48,
    online: false
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};
```

Then I go through this and I get the names back, which is what I expect:

```
for (user in users) {
    console.log(user);
}

// Alan
// Jeff
// Sarah
// Ryan
```

then I do this, and get undefined four times

```
for (user in users) {
  console.log(user.age);
}
// undefined
// undefined
// undefined
// undefined
```

Then I do THIS and I can access the age property

```
users.Alan.age
```

What is going on here??

Comment: If user is the *name*, the string, why did you expect it to have an age property?

Comment: You are referencing the key, not the object... the console.log(user) line clearly shows that.

Comment: You want `users[user].age`

Comment: The for look does not look over the objects -- it loops over the property names.  You could also make an array and then have it behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the value from the object rather than the key. You can select the user from the users object and then the age.

```
for (user in users) {
  console.log(users[user].age);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be more standard to make users an array like this:

```
let users = [
  {
    name: 'Alan',
    age: 27,
    online: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Jeff',
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Sarah',
    age: 48,
    online: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Ryan',
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
];
```

I think this would probably "act" the way you expect.  *(Where each element of the users object is an object.)*